# Drawing countour lines on a map Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-basemap

i am trying to draw contour lines on a world map, the lines represent the magnetic declination in a specific latitude and longitude.

My current code is such:

```
def frange(start, stop, step):
x = start
while x < stop:
        yield x
        x += step
 m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=8000000,
        resolution='l',projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=-10,lat_0=-10,lon_0=-70)
 m.drawcoastlines()
 m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
 m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
 delta=0.5
 x=[]
 y=[]
 for i in frange(-80,-29.5,delta):
    x.append(i)
for j in frange(-40,10.5,delta):
    y.append(i)
with open("magdecl.txt", "r") as ins:
z = []
for line in ins:
    z.append(float(line))
 CS = m.contour(x,y,z)
 plt.save("magdecl")
 plt.show()
```

But this code is returning such error:

IndexError: too many indices for array

And i cant find the solution anywhere, the contour documentation doest help either.
Please help me fix my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any reason not to use geopandas?

Comment: I never used geopandas. Just got used on plotting maps this way.

Comment: I don't think there is any need for an additional package like geopandas here. But the problem is caused by how the data is read in and/or used. `contour` needs a 2D array as input for the Z argument. This seems not to be the case here. Since we have no information about your data at all, we cannot help you further. See [mcve].